# Why is this contains text based sumif formula not working in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I got the following text in cell A1:

```
GF HTG SHEET 1 (Drawing Reference- 21)
```

I got the following data:

| ColE | ColF |
| --- | --- |
| GF HTG SHEET 1 | 10 |
| GF HTG SHEET 1 | 20 |
| GF HTG SHEET 1 | 10 |

So the formula I'm trying to get to work is this one:

```
=SUMIF($E$2:$E$4,"*"&A1&"*",$F$2:$F$4)
```

It give me 0, while all instructions I've seen online point me to the approach above.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: `"*"&A1&"*"` means the data in colE contains at least A1, and you are looking for the opposite.

Comment: I see....@MikeSteelson! So...to do it the other around would have to be following your answer below? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=sumproduct(arrayformula(if(iserror(SEARCH(E2:E,$A$1)),0,1))*(F2:F))
```

[image]